# How to format a number in template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Since the Angular 2 documentation is really poor, I have a question:

I have a number:

`{{ -1739034 | percent : '1.2-2'}}` and it is displayed as :  `-1,739,034`.

How can I transform it into  `-1'739'034`?

Thanks!

Comment: you probably need to create a custom pipe with the pattern you want. There are good examples how to create your own pipes. Google it ;)

Comment: I actually thought that problem is internationalization...

Comment: In that case please edit your question tags to add internationalization and remove js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **[locale-number.pipe.ts](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/83e413f812cbe3e5e9982a1d9b069750faf62887/src/pipes/locale-number.pipe.ts)** -- it modifies the pipes from angular 2 to take an additional parameter for setting the locale

The locale you are looking for is `de-CH` (Switzerland)

Try `number.toLocaleString('de-CH', { style: 'decimal' })` and verify for yourself